# t.context scoping in ava

Tags: javascript, node.js, ava

I'm 90% sure of what is causing the problem but I'd like to clarify how ava handles t.context. Here is my scenario:

```
const lMockManager = ImportMock.mockClass<zmq.Dealer>(zmq, "Dealer");
lMockManager.mock(Symbol.asyncIterator, lNewIterator);

test.before((t: ExecutionContext<TTestContext) =>
{
    t.context =
    {
        DummyData: [],
        PromiseCallback: null,
        ZMQMock: lMockManager,
    };

    const lNewIterator = (() =>
    {
        return {
            async next()
            {
                return new Promise((resolve: (aValue: string[]) => void): void =>
                {
                    t.context.PromiseCallback = resolve;
                });
            },
        };
    })();

});

test("Receive Message", (t: ExecutionContext<TTestContext) =>
{
    const lMessageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();  // Imports ZMQ as a dep
    lMessageReceiver.Start();  // This triggers the creation of t.PromiseCallback

    t.context.PromiseCallback("hello world"); // Error: t.context.PromiseCallback is null
});
```

For testing purposes I pushed `test.before()`'s `t.context` into a global object and compared it against `test()`'s `t.context` and confirmed that the objects are indeed different. So I assume `test()` is passed a deepCopy of `t.context`.

This makes sense to avoid having `test()` modify the shared `t.context`. So this behaviour combined with me setting `lNewIterator` inside `test.before()`, means that I modify the shared `t.context` after the test starts but because each test has a local deep copy, they do not received the modifications.

I will setup `lNewIterator` within `test()` as modifying the shared `t.context` after `test.before()` exits seems like an anti-pattern.

Comment: What is `t`, what is `MessageReceiver`, and why do you expect the `lNewIterator` object to be used by anything?

Comment: Good questions, I have added some extra code for context (including some types). `t` is `ava`'s exection conext, it gets passed by the ava test runner into the relevant test functions (`test.before` and `test`).

`MessageReceiver` is the class under test. I have passed `lNewIterator` to one of `MessageReceiver`'s mocked dependencies. `lNewIterator`'s result will be returned to `MessageReceiver` when it interacts with the `asyncIterator` of the injected dependency (`zmq` is the injected dependency.

Comment: The result that gets returned to `MessageReceiver` will be a promise. The resolver of this promise will sit within the object `t.context` inside `test.before`

Comment: "*I have passed `lNewIterator` to one of `MessageReceiver`'s mocked dependencies.*" - no, or at least, not in the code you've posted. The `const lNewIterator =` is a local variable in the `before` callback that is never used. Did you place the `lMockManager.mock(Symbol.asyncIterator, lNewIterator);` inside there as well?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, `lNewIterator`'s result is being passed as the 2nd argument to `lMockManager.mock()`. This then stores the result and returns it each time the subject under test calls `Symbol.asyncIterator`.

Comment: I saw `lMockManager.mock(Symbol.asyncIterator, lNewIterator);`, but that happens with an undeclared variable *before* the `lNewIterator` is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.context` from `test.before()` is indeed copied, though shallowly. Try storing the callback on an object like `t.context.callback = { fn: null }` or something along those lines.

Looking at your injection code I think you may be better off using serial tests and `beforeEach()` hooks.